# sqlite3 foreign keys "remembered"?

Tags: python, sqlite

I really, really hope I'm simply doing something wrong.

I have two tables and a mapping table; the latter's two columns reference the respective primary keys of the others. Deleting one of the data rows does not work if a mapping exists; this is expected. However, deleting the mapping should allow me to delete the data row, but I get an IntegrityError when I try to do so.

Example code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')
fk = (conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys").fetchone()[0])
print 'version = %s, foreign keys = %r' % (sqlite3.sqlite_version, bool(fk))
if not fk:
  raise Exception('No foreign keys!?')

c = conn.cursor()
c.executescript('''
create table if not exists main.one (resource_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, data TEXT);
create table if not exists main.two (node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data TEXT);
create table if not exists main.mapping (node_id INTEGER REFERENCES two, resource_id TEXT REFERENCES one);
insert into main.one(resource_id, data) values('A', 'A one thing');
insert into main.two(node_id, data) values(1, 'A two thing');
insert into main.mapping(resource_id, node_id) values('A', 1);
insert into main.one(resource_id, data) values('B', 'Another one thing');
insert into main.two(node_id, data) values(2, 'Another two thing');
insert into main.mapping(resource_id, node_id) values('B', 2);
insert into main.one(resource_id, data) values('C', 'Yet another one thing');
''')
for tbl in 'one', 'two', 'mapping':
  print 'TABLE main.%s:\n%s\n' % (tbl, '\n'.join(repr(r) for r in c.execute('select * from main.%s' % tbl).fetchall()))

del_cmd = """delete from main.one where resource_id='B'"""
print 'Attempting: %s' % (del_cmd,)
try:
  c.execute(del_cmd)
except Exception, e:
  print 'Failed to delete: %s' % e

cmd = """delete from main.one where resource_id='C'"""
print 'Attempting: %s' % (cmd,)
c.execute(cmd)

cmd = """delete from main.mapping where resource_id='B' AND node_id=2"""
print '\nAttempting: %s' % (cmd,)
c.execute(cmd)

for tbl in 'one', 'two', 'mapping':
  print 'TABLE main.%s:\n%s\n' % (tbl, '\n'.join(repr(r) for r in c.execute('select * from main.%s' % tbl).fetchall()))

print 'Attempting: %s' % (del_cmd,)
c.execute(del_cmd)
```

I'd expect all of that to print the various table contents and progress. However, the very last DELETE violates a foreign key constraint that I cannot find:

```
$ python test.py                                                                                                                                               
version = 3.6.22, foreign keys = True
TABLE main.one:
(u'A', u'A one thing')
(u'B', u'Another one thing')
(u'C', u'Yet another one thing')

TABLE main.two:
(1, u'A two thing')
(2, u'Another two thing')

TABLE main.mapping:
(1, u'A')
(2, u'B')

Attempting: delete from main.one where resource_id='B'
Failed to delete: foreign key constraint failed
Attempting: delete from main.one where resource_id='C'

Attempting: delete from main.mapping where resource_id='B' AND node_id=2
TABLE main.one:
(u'A', u'A one thing')
(u'B', u'Another one thing')

TABLE main.two:
(1, u'A two thing')
(2, u'Another two thing')

TABLE main.mapping:
(1, u'A')

Attempting: delete from main.one where resource_id='B'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    c.execute(del_cmd)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: foreign key constraint failed
```

WTF?

Comment: Can you simplify the code presentation of the problem? I'd like to take a look but I'm not wading through all that, and many others won't either. Make a minimal demo and who knows, maybe the answer will pop out at you...

Comment: I cut and pasted your code exactly as posted, and it ran fine, the delete didn't fail, and printing the tables afterward shows the row was deleted.

Comment: mita, which sqlite and python version?

Comment: SOLVED: As it turns out, sqlite 3.6.22 is simply buggy - this has nothing to do with foreign keys. When going through the python bindings, deletes are sometimes not applied correctly; I haven't identified a way to get entirely repeatable behaviour other than the failing case above, and I haven't tested any other bindings or the C API directly. I'll need to upgrade on all target systems, respectively provide a newer version to go with my code.

Comment: Still reproducible in Python 2.7.5 on Windows. Reported upstream: http://bugs.python.org/issue19450